# No route matches [POST] in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `pending request` page I have some requests that I am getting from other users, with these requests two buttons are attached `accept` and `cancel`, when I click on accept button, then request is accepted and below is the code of accept request in the create method

```
  def create
    @user = Userrequest.select(:RequestFrom).where('RequestTo = ? AND IsApproved = ?', current_user.id, "0")
    requestfrom = @user.RequestFrom
    Userrequest.update_attributes('RequestFrom = ? AND RequestTo = ? AND IsApproved = ?', requestfrom,current_user.id,"1")
    @user_request = Userrequest.new( :RequestFrom => requestfrom , :RequestTo => current_user.id , :IsApproved => "1" , :SkillType => "" )
    @user_request.save
    redirect_to '/default'
  end
```

in the create method, I am doing accept request work and after accept request, it should redirect to `default` page. But when I click on accept button it gets me error below:

```
No route matches [POST] "/pendingrequest"
```

And below is the route:

```
match '/pendingrequests', to: 'static_pages#create', via: 'get'
```

And below is my accept request button:

```
<table width="50%">
   <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="button">
          <%= button_to "Accept", '/pendingrequests', { method: :get, :class => "buttonblck" } %>
        </div> 
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Kindle suggest me where I make mistake, waiting for your reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type command in terminal:

```
rake routes
```

It is often helps to understand why no route mathes.

try this match

```
match '/static_pages', to: 'static_pages#create', via: :get, as: '/pendingrequests'
```

or

```
match '/static_pages', to: 'static_pages#create', via: :post, as: '/pendingrequests'
```

or

```
match '/static_pages', to: 'static_pages#create', via: :all, as: '/pendingrequests'
```

Answer (score 0):

> No route matches [POST] "/pendingrequest"

The http method is `POST`, but you defined the route use `get`.

Change `via: 'get'` to `via: 'post'`

```
match '/pendingrequests', to: 'static_pages#create', via: 'post'
```

Comment: For rails 4, you can directly write `post '/pendingrequests', to: 'static_pages#create'`

Answer (score 0):

You can change like this

**Button**

```
<%= button_to "Accept", "/pendingrequests", method: :post %>
```

**Routes**

```
post '/pendingrequests', to: 'static_pages#create'
```